# How do I find all the hermitian matrices satisfying a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra

I find this exercise in my textbook.

> Find all Hermitian matrices $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying $$A^5+A^3+A-3I=0$$

I have two questions.

1) How do I solve a matrix polynomial? If I simply factorize it, I can only get those answers with the form $\lambda I$.

2) How a matrix being Hermitian (basically it means a matrix is "complexly" symmetric) makes it special in this problem?

Comment: There is no general way by abel-ruffini (for the 'easy' case $n=1$). In this case try Jordan normal form, maybe it will help

Comment: Hermitian matrices are diagonalizable, so this reduces to a question about scalars satisfying the given polynomial constraint.

Comment: @Belgi: That is not true, $x=1$ satisfies the equation, reducing to $(x-1)(x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+3)$ wihch can be solved :-).

Comment: @copper.hat - I said "in general" because q1 of the OP is general

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only real root  of $x^5+x^3+x-3$ is $1$. Hence the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$, so $A$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: but the matrix can have non-real eigenvalues to, no ?

Comment: @Belgi: Being Hermitian ensures all of its eigenvalues are real.